# error: package javafx.scene.media does not exist

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create javafx media player as gradle project, but got this error.**error: package javafx.scene.media does not exist** on line: ***import javafx.scene.media.Media;***

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'

}

group 'life.antonov'
version '1.0'

mainClassName='life.antonov.muza.Main'
sourceCompatibility = 11

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: '13'
    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: '13 '
    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-media', version: '13'


}
```

I'm tried to unzip downloaded javafx-media jar file and it is almost empty:

```
$ unzip javafx-media-13.jar 
Archive:  javafx-media-13.jar
   creating: META-INF/
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Why?
Maybe I wrote wrong dependencies?
What I have to do to make my application compile and work?

Comment: When using the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin, don't declare any JavaFX dependencies in the `dependencies` block.

Comment: When using JavaFX I recommend using Maven and a modular system to manage the dependencies and deployment because thanks to Oracle it can get very messy.

Comment: So I don't like maven, I love gradle. And I want on any other machine do "git clone && ./gradlew build && java -jar ... " and I want this to work properly. If I don't use dependencies it will not work.  Solution proposed by MelvinWM works!

Comment: "If I don't use dependencies it will not work". Yes, it will. The JavaFX plugin implicitly adds the dependencies for you based on the modules you specified in the plugin's extension. You re-declaring the same dependencies in the `dependencies` block is unnecessary duplication at best. In your case, you add them without a classifier (i.e. `win`, `mac`, or `linux`) which resolves to empty JAR files. The JavaFX plugin derives the correct classifier from the host OS (parts of JavaFX are platform-specific), which is why the below answer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tested it, but:

Replace:

```
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
```

With

```
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media' ]
```

Comment: @MaximAntonov Also please do accept this answer as the solution and upvote it if the answer solves your problem and you think it is good :).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use MediaView control in `javafx` you must to do 2 steps

**Step1:** add requires javafx.media;

```
module com.codegym.videoplayerfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media; // You must add this line


    opens com.codegym.videoplayerfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.codegym.videoplayerfx;
}
```

**Step2:** Add dependency in pom.xml for maven (or build.gradle for gradle). After that **you must press build**. Try orther **dependency version** if does't work

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, to use with controls, module-info should be

```
module com.murray {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media; // You must add this line
    exports com.yourApp;
}
```

And you need two entries in the dependency tag of pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```